# using hadoop on the current application

Tags: java, hadoop, bigdata

we have an application which is written in `Java`, and uses `solr`,`Elastic Search`, `Neo4j`,`MySQL` and few more .

we require to increase our data size dramatically (from millions to billions)

So here the options I had in order to make this work:

1. clustering individual components notably `solr, ES, Neo4j` and `MySQl`
2. use what everyone talks about nowadays : `Hadoop`

Problem with first is hard to manage

the second option sounds too good to be true. So my questions are :

1. Can I actually assume that Hadoop can do that before digging in?
2. what other criteria do I need to consider?
3. Is there any alternative solution for such task?

Answer (score 0):

Solr is for data searching. If you want to process the big data (meets criteria of volume, velocity and variety) such as ETL and reporting, you would need Hadoop.

Hadoop consist of several eco system components. You can refer to below link for documentation:

https://hadoop.apache.org